# How to get the main source file name from an IOTAProject?

Tags: delphi, toolsapi

Since at least D2007 a project file can have a main source file with differing base name. The DevExpress demos make use of this: E.g. there is a single dpr file UnboundListDemo.dpr which serves as the main source for both UnboundListDemoD11.dproj and UnboundListDemoD12.dproj.

Now if I have a `Project: IOTAProject` then `Project.FileName` returns the dproj file name. I couldn't find an "official" way to get the dpr's file name. Is there any? One can get it from parsing the dproj file (see [here](http://blog.lextudio.com/2008/02/grapevine-voice-rad-studio-ota-issue/)) but I'd prefer a ToolsAPI method.

---

**Edit:** I came up with this code based on [Jon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2028046/how-to-get-the-main-source-file-name-from-an-iotaproject/2028842#2028842):

```
function IsProjectSource(const FileName: string): Boolean;
begin
  Result := IsDpr(FileName) or IsBpr(FileName) or IsPackage(FileName);
end;

function GxOtaGetProjectFileName2(Project: IOTAProject; NormalizeBdsProj: Boolean = False): string;
var
  i: Integer;
  Module: IOTAModule;
  Editor: IOTAEditor;
begin
  Result := '';
  if Assigned(Project) then begin
    Result := Project.FileName;
    if NormalizeBdsProj and IsBdsprojOrDproj(Result) then begin
      Module := Project as IOTAModule;
      for i := 0 to Module.ModuleFileCount - 1 do
      begin
        Editor := Module.ModuleFileEditors[i];
        if IsProjectSource(Editor.FileName) then begin
          Result := Editor.FileName;
          Exit;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

where the Is... routines are from [GX_GenericUtils](http://gexperts.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/gexperts/trunk/Source/Utils/GX_GenericUtils.pas?revision=529&view=markup).

---

**Edit 2:** How to create one of these situations:

1. Create new VCL application.
2. Save as MyProject.dproj.
3. Close project in IDE.
4. In Windows explorer, rename MyProject.dproj to MyProjectD11.dproj.
5. From now on be sure to open MyProjectD11.dproj, **not** MyProject.dpr!

Comment: Could you please give an example how different names for .dpr and .dproj work? Does that just mean, the same .dpr file is referenced in multiple .dproj files?

Comment: Multiple .dproj files are the case I encountered. I don't know how the DX people created them. Maybe simply like here: http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=57890 in the steps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you iterate the editors on the IOTAProject instance, you'll probably find the dpr.

```
var
  Module: IOTAModule;
  Project: IOTAProject;
  Editor: IOTAEditor;
begin
  // Set Project Here....
  Module := Project as IOTAModule;
  for I := 0 to Module.ModuleFileCount - 1 do
  begin
    Editor := Module.ModuleFileEditors[I];

  end;
end;
```

Comment: OK, that gives *.dpr and *.res in my test case. I can look for all dpr/dpk/bpk/... files and hope I'll find only one. That's more work and less reliable than I hoped, but better than nothing. I'll have to play with that.